# Elegant way to replace parens

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace matching pairs of `<>` and `()` with `[]`. For example,

```
abc(def)hij -> abc[def]hij
abc<def>hij -> abc[def]hij
```

What I do is like this:

```
function getParensReplaced(str) {
    return str && str.replace(/<([^>]+)>/g, function(str, p){
        return '[' + p + ']';
    }).replace(/\(([^\)]+)\)/g, function(str, p){
        return '[' + p + ']';
    });
}
```

But it doesn't look good. Any idea to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
\([^\)]*?\)|<[^>]*?>
```

So that would make:

```
function getParensReplaced(str) {
    return str && str.replace(/\(([^\)]*?)\)|<([^>]*?)>/g, function(str, p,q){
        return (p == undefined) ?  '[' + q + ']': '[' + p + ']';
    });
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GgrQm/

Comment: Now it is, check the fiddle. But as others stated, regex might be overkill, I just wanted to improve our sample. This is hower, the easiest to expand with more complex stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use simple function rather than regular expression as below ?

```
str ="abc<def>hij and abc(def)hij";
console.log(str);
function Replacer(str){
 return str.replace("<","[").replace(">","]").replace("(","[").replace(")","]")
}
console.log(Replacer(str));
```

Comment: Agreed; this is the simplest and likely most efficient way to do this. Unless there is some other requirement that is unstated in the original question, like balancing parens (which the original doesn't do anyway), there is no need to pull out the regular expression engine.

Comment: `str.replace(/<\(/,"[").replace(/>|\)/,"]")`

Comment: There can be just single `<` or `>`. That's why I used regex. Good point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Or yet another:

```
// replace <> and () with []

var re0 = /[<\(]/g;
var re1 = /[\)>]/g;
var s = '<here> are (some) angle <brackets> and (round ones)';

alert(s.replace(re0, '[').replace(re1,']'));
```

Comment: There can be just single < or >.

Comment: Not a problem, the above doesn't need them to be in pairs.

Comment: I mean a single bracket shouldn't be changed.:)

Comment: You should put that in the question then, something like "replace matching pairs of <> and () with []".